# Send message by socket using lNet

Tags: sockets, delphi, pascal, lazarus

I use lNet for tcp socket connection.

In usage documentation (https://lnet.wordpress.com/usage/sockets-protocols-and-sending) is that I should use:

```
Sent := FConnection.SendMessage(TempBuffer, aSocket);
```

instead

```
aSocket.SendMessage(TempBuffer);
```

I can't understandy why. Could you explain? :(

Comment: Perhaps, to be in order to know how many bytes have actually been sent?

Answer (score 0):

The author (Almindor) recommends it in case you uses higher level protocols like FTP. If you use direct (raw) TCP/UDP, there's not a problem to use it directly. If possible, it's better to send and receive through the connection object (FConnection in the example).